# SAMLv2 - processing rules for IssueInstant?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

Reading the SAMLv2 specification documents it seems that no checking of the value for `IssueInstant` should be performed in contrast to the `Conditions` of an Assertion.

Is this impression correct?

Thanks and regards,
Bernhard

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Per the SAML 2.0 Core Spec -

> Note that the time period specified by the optional NotBefore and
>   NotOnOrAfter attributes, if present, SHOULD fall within the overall
>   assertion validity period as specified by the  element's
>   NotBefore and NotOnOrAfter attributes. If both attributes are present,
>   the value for NotBefore MUST be less than (earlier than) the value for
>   NotOnOrAfter.

I'm not aware of any specific processing rules for IssueInstant explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The linked specification

[Security and Privacy Considerations for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-sec-consider-2.0-os.pdf)

tells ...

> A Service Provider site MAY choose to implement a stricter test of
>   validity for SSO assertions, such as requiring the assertion’s
>   IssueInstant or AuthnInstant attribute value to be within a few
>   minutes of the time at which the assertion is received at the Service
>   Provider site.